# Get all unordered list elements and their text

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to retrieve an unordered list along with all the elements within it. The <ul> has <li>'s with cities' names as text and I want to get those cities.

I can't seem to get the text content back. Using console.log I was able to figure out it doesn't go through the for loop and returns this error.

> Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: cityArray is not defined

```
var cityArray = [];
    await page
      .$eval(
        "body > div.page > div.container.account.cf > div.account-content > div.addressPage > div.addressCard.addAddressCard > div:nth-child(6) > ul",
        (ul) => {
          console.log(ul.innerHTML);
          var ulHtml = ul.innerHTML;
          
          for (let i = 0; i < ulHtml.childElementCount; i++) {
            cityArray.push(ulHtml.children[i].textContent);
          }
          console.log("returning")
          return cityArray;
        }
      )
      .then((cityArray) => {
        console.log(cityArray);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript assumes that `cityArray` is a local variable in the function. Declare `cityArray`inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your selector. If it's possible, give "ul" a class otherwise use parent's class. Your way is definitely not alright.

```
let cities = [...document.querySelector(".addressCard li")];
cities.forEach(city => cityArray.push(city.innerText));
```